# Comparing fractions using pointers program in C efficient method

Tags: c

How to compare 2 fractions that are stored in pointer instances?
consider the below code:

```
struct frac {
 int num;
 int denom;
};
```

We need to implement : fr_equal(a,b) returns true if *a is equal to *b.

```
bool fr_equal(const struct frac *a, const struct frac *b);
```

I am facing difficulties in this, my code is as below:

```
bool fr_equal(const struct frac *a, const struct frac *b) {

    if ( (*a).num != 0 && (*b).num !=0)
    {
        int x = (*a).num;
        int y = (*a).denom;
        int m = (*b).num;
        int n = (*b).denom;

        if (x==m && y==n )
            return true;

        if (x%y==0)
            y=y/x;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My code is incomplete, as I haven't understood how to proceed and what all cases to consider. I could have 4 cases but its too long.

Can anyone tell me a **short and efficient way of doing this**

Thanks!

Comment: There are standard functions that use a comparison function, and it has the following signature `int (*compar)(const void *, const void *, void *)`, maybe you should stick to it in case you need `qsort()` or `bsearch()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand what the rest of your code is trying to do.

From your explanation, can't you just do this:

```
bool fr_equal(const struct frac *a, const struct frac *b)
{
    return a->num == b->num && a->denom == b->denom;
}
```

If you are trying to account for mathematical equality with reducible fractions, I think this suggestion from void_ptr would cover it.

```
bool fr_equal(const struct frac *a, const struct frac *b)
{
    return (a->num * b->denom) == (b->num * a->denom);
}
```

As I think about it, the following should also be a valid approach, although it requires some additional error checking to prevent divide by zero.

```
bool fr_equal(const struct frac *a, const struct frac *b)
{
    // WARNING: Needs to include code to avoid divide by zero
    return ((double)a->num / a->denom) == ((double)b->num / a->denom);
}
```

Comment: `return a->num * b->denom == b->num * a->denom;` will take care of reducible fractions.

Comment: Testing floating point numbers for equality is walking on a mine field. Better not go there. ;)

Comment: @void_ptr: Yes, it would only be safe for smaller fractions. Your idea was better.

Comment: There is also the minor point that the multiplications can (for some values of numerator and denominator) overflow.  Which produces undefined results for ints.

Comment: @Rob - Right, up-casting to `long long` would be a safer way, I think.

Comment: @void_ptr - That just changes the values for which overflow will occur.  It doesn't eliminate the concern.   All basic signed integral types in C can overflow, and the result is undefined.

Comment: @Rob - His fractions are `int`s, so `long long` should be just long enough to hold a result of any multiplication. I see another answer given that covers this subject nicely with more portable type names.

Comment: @void_ptr.   True, void_pointer.   But if the members of the struct were changed to long long, the problem would return.

Answer (score 1):

If your function takes in two fractions that are not fully reduced, you can use the gcd algorithm:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
  if (a == 0) return b;
  return gcd(b % a, a);
}
```

and then in your function, find the gcd of both your numerator and denominator using:

```
int r_factor = gcd(a->num, a->denom);
```

and reduce your fraction.

Followed by that, you do the same thing for b, and compare the two.

```
bool fr_equal(const struct frac *a, const struct frac *b) {
  int r_factor = gcd(a->num, a->denom);
  a->num /= r_factor;
  a->denom /= r_factor;

  r_factor = gcd(b->num, b->denom);
  b->num /= r_factor;
  b->denom /= r_factor;

  return (a->num == b->num && a->denom == b->denom);
}
```

Comment: That gcd() function does not work as advertised.   I assume you intended a recursive function, in which case the return statement would be "return gcd ( b%a, a )".   And your comparison function changes const variables, so will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way to compare a/b to c/d for equality is to compare a*d == b*c.  However, that's going to overflow sooner than slower methods.  If you have C99 support and the `<stdint.h>` header, you could use int32_t for the numerator and denominator, then:

```
bool fr_equal(const frac *lh, const frac *rh)
{
    return (int64_t)lh->num*rh->denom == (int64_t)rh->num*lh->denom;
}
```

Otherwise, it might be best to cast to double instead of int64_t.  That's as fast as 64-bit int arithmetic on modern desktop/notebook processors (maybe not on low-power mobile and very unlikely on embedded processors), so not much is given up other than false positives for very-nearly-equal fractions with large common denominators.

If you have arranged the type so that the denominators are always positive, you can do ordered comparisons, too.  For example, a/b < c/d iff ad < bc, provided that bd>0.